# Android getting dynamic permission from third party defined permissions

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, wear-os

I'm working on a project that tries to send data from Android app to Tizen wear watch. I have a sample app provided by Samsung but this is super old which is based on Eclipse, (R.I.P).

So, I created a sample app and the first step is to get permissions (for Marshmallow OS). These permissions have provided by sample code in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.WATCH_APP_TYPE.Companion" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION" />
```

So, I'm trying to get these permissions on App launch.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check permissions
        getPermissions();
    }

    public void getPermissions()
    {
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, 
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, 
            "com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK", 
            "com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY", 
            "com.samsung.WATCH_APP_TYPE.Companion", 
            "com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION"}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        for(int i : grantResults)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Result: " + i);
        }

        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[5] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    displayMessage("Permissions granted");
                }
                else
                {
                    displayMessage("Please accept permissions to proceed.");
                    this.finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayMessage(String message)
    {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

When I run it, no permission request dialog displays even for Bluetooth and app closes obviously (due to code). I see following result in Log:

```
D/MainActivity: Result: 0
D/MainActivity: Result: 0
D/MainActivity: Result: -1
D/MainActivity: Result: -1
D/MainActivity: Result: -1
D/MainActivity: Result: -1
```

For some reasons Android automatically give me Bluetooth permission but have no idea how to get those Samsung permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only [specific dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups) are require [requesting them at run time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Therefore you should not need to write any permissions related code to be granted any of those permissions.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, So this is the explanation of why I don't see Dialog for Bluetooth. What about Samsung permissions? Does it mean only Android dangerous permissions must be taken on app launch and those Samsung permissions are already granted (Since they are not Android permissions)?

Comment: Correct: only those ones in the table need to be requested - the Samsung ones should be granted automatically.

Comment: I have the same issue. The samsung permissions are not granted despite being declared in the manifest file. So I get an error in trying to access the data. Any idea of how to get the permission granted?